# Finding the number of intersections of a function and $y = x$

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification

> Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function defined for all real numbers $x$ such that $|f(x) -f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2} |x-y|$ for all x,y. Then the number of points of intersection of the graph of $y = f(x)$ and the line $y = x$ is
>
> A) $0$
>
> $\boxed{B)1}$
>
> C) $2$
>
> D)none of the foregoing numbers.

**My Method:**
Consider $x = y + h$,
We have:

$|f(y+h) - f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2} |h|$

$\implies \frac{|f(y+h) - f(y)|}{|h|} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(y+h) - f(y)|}{|h|} \leq \frac{1}{2}  \hspace{2cm}     \ldots (1)$

$\implies |f'(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies \frac{-1}{2} \leq f'(y) \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$\implies \frac{-y}{2} \leq f(y) \leq \frac{y}{2}  \hspace{2cm} \ldots (2)$

Thus we have,

$ f(x) \in [\frac{-x}{2} , \frac{x}{2}]$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

[image: graph]

The graph of $f(x)$ must lie within the shaded portion and thus we have no solutions for $x>0$ but from the bounds it is clear that $f(0) = 0$ and we have one intersection at $(0,0)$.

The shaded portion is $ \frac{-x}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{x}{2}$ and the green line is $y = x$,

Which gives us a total of $1$ intersection.

But would limit in $(1)$ necessarily exist and can $(2)$ be directly written from the previous step.

Would be glad if the community could come up with any alternative approaches (using elementary methods).

Comment: $f$ may not be differentiable...

Comment: and moreover you forgot a constant when you integrate. $f(0)=0$ is not always true

Comment: You can actually bound $f(x)$ similarly as you have done, but the bound must depend on $f(0)$. Once you get there, prove there exist an intersection, and then from there you prove it is unique

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $1/2<1$, $f$ has a unique fixpoint, by the fix point theorem of Banach.

Comment: Is an elementary solution using high school calculus methods possible?